# How to get a list of Joomla usernames with ID-link of secific group?

Tags: joomla, get, usergroups

Is it possible to get a list of users of a specific usergroup, for exmplample group "Registered Users", with a simple href-link of their UserID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registered users belong to the group with id 2. I tried to find group names constant somewhere, but I failed when I was researching for my project, so I ended up making my own constants.

Anyway, to get users who belong to a group, you can use

```
$registeredUsers = JAccess::getUsersByGroup(2); // in my project it was $self::REGISTERED_GROUP
```

Add

```
jimport('joomla.access.access');
jimport('joomla.user.user');
```

before if neccessary classes are not loaded.

Then you could do

```
foreach($registeredUsers as $user_id) {
    $user = JFactory::getUser($user_id);
    echo $user->name;
}
```

**Important:** Make sure before selecting users using the `id` passed in the link that it belongs to id group list which you want exposed. I guess you wouldn't want to expose super administrator usernames etc

Comment: Do I have to "start" JFactory first? Myabe this is a stupid question, sry.

Comment: You should be able to use it directly like in my example

Comment: It works and lists users within the same group. Big thx! But how do I output a href-link after each username with the users-ID? Like user1 = 01, user2 = 02?

Comment: @Dataminer You have user id and user name, can't you just make the link, I mean it's basic html? Also, consider accepting answer if it helped

Comment: My fault! *blush* It's exactly what I was looking for. BIG THANKS! You dont have a site with donate option? ;)